# C++ convert UTF8 char array to CP1250

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries, iconv

I have a problem converting UTF8 encoded char array to CP1250 encoded char array.

I tried making a static iconv lib, but when compiling my UTF8->CP1250 code it always fail with

```
1>foo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol libiconv_close
1>foo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol libiconv_open
1>foo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol libiconv
```

I also tried a lot of compiled static libraries, but always the same error.

Doesn't matter if `/MD` or `/MT` is set.

I do not insist on using `iconv`. Is there any other simple solution for this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're coding in Windows, why not use the Windows API. Use `MultiByteToWideChar` to convert losslessly up to UTF-16. Then use `WideCharToMultiByte` to convert down to e.g. CP 1250.

---

**Addendum**: the code below seems to work OK.

```
#include <assert.h>             // assert
#include <iostream>             // std::wcout, std::wcerr
#include <iterator>             // std::begin, std::end
#include <string>               // std::string, std::wstring
#include <stddef.h>             // ptrdiff_t
#include <stdexcept>            // std::system_error
#include <stdlib.h>             // EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <string.h>             // memcmp
#include <system_error>         // std::system_error etc.

// Example of how to include Microsoft's <windows.h>.
// More support stuff is generally needed for more serious code.
#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#undef NOMINMAX
#define NOMINMAX
#undef STRICT
#define STRICT
#include <windows.h>            // E_FAIL, etc.

namespace cppx {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    using std::error_code;
    using std::string;
    using std::system_error;
    using std::system_category;

    typedef unsigned char   Byte;
    typedef ptrdiff_t       Size;

    template< class Type >
    auto size( Type const& c )
        -> Size
    { return end( c ) - begin( c ); }

    auto hopefully( bool const condition ) -> bool { return condition; }

    auto fail(
        string const&   message,
        int const       code    = 0
        )
        -> bool
    {
        throw system_error(
            error_code( code, system_category() ), message
            );
    }
}  // namespace cppx

namespace data {
    using cppx::Byte;
    using cppx::hopefully;
    using cppx::fail;
    using std::string;
    using std::wstring;

    char const utf8_bom[] = "\xEF\xBB\xBF";

    template< class Type, int n >
    auto dummy()
        -> Type&
    { static Type the_dummy; return the_dummy; }

    auto utf16_from_utf8( char const* bytes, int length )
        -> wstring
    {
        if( length >= 3 && ::memcmp( bytes, utf8_bom, 3 ) == 0 )
        {
            bytes += 3;  length -= 3;
        }

        assert( length >= 0 );
        if( length == 0 ) { return L""; }

        int const buffer_size = ::MultiByteToWideChar(
            CP_UTF8,
            0,                  // flags, must be 0 for UTF-8
            bytes,
            length,
            nullptr,            // output buffer
            0                   // buffer size
            );
        hopefully( buffer_size > 0 )
            || fail( "MultiByteToWideChar (1st call)", ::GetLastError() );

        wstring result( buffer_size, L'#' );
        int const n_encoding_values = ::MultiByteToWideChar(
            CP_UTF8,
            0,                  // flags, must be 0 for UTF-8
            bytes,
            length,
            &result[0],         // output buffer
            buffer_size
            );
        hopefully( n_encoding_values > 0 )
            || fail( "MultiByteToWideChar (2nd call)", ::GetLastError() );
        assert( n_encoding_values <= buffer_size );

        result.resize( n_encoding_values );     // Possible down-sizing.
        return result;
    }

    auto utf16_from_utf8( Byte const* const bytes, int const length )
        -> wstring
    {
        return utf16_from_utf8( reinterpret_cast<char const*>( bytes ), length );
    }

    auto sbcs_from(
        wchar_t const* const    s,
        int const               length,
        unsigned const          codepage            = ::GetACP(),
        bool&                   used_default_char   = dummy<bool, 1>()
        )
        -> string
    {
        assert( codepage != CP_UTF8 );
        if( length == 0 ) { return ""; }

        DWORD const         flags           = WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS;     // Must be 0 for UTF-8.
        char const* const   default_char    = "\x7F";                   // ASCII DEL

        int const buffer_size = WideCharToMultiByte(
            codepage,
            flags,
            s,
            length,
            nullptr,            // buffer
            0,                  // buffer size
            default_char,
            nullptr
            );
        hopefully( buffer_size > 0 )
            || fail( "WideCharToMultiByte (1st call)", ::GetLastError() );

        string  result              = string( buffer_size, '#' );
        BOOL    defaulted           = false;
        int const n_bytes = WideCharToMultiByte(
            codepage,
            flags,
            s,
            length,
            &result[0],         // buffer
            buffer_size,
            default_char,
            &defaulted
            );
        hopefully( n_bytes > 0 )
            || fail( "WideCharToMultiByte (2nd call)", ::GetLastError() );
        assert( n_bytes <= buffer_size );

        result.resize( n_bytes );
        used_default_char = !!defaulted;
        return result;
    }

    auto sbcs_from(
        wstring const&          s,
        unsigned const          codepage            = ::GetACP(),
        bool&                   used_default_char   = dummy<bool, 1>()
        )
        -> string
    {
        if( s.length() == 0 ) { return ""; }
        return sbcs_from( &s[0], s.length(), codepage, used_default_char );
    }

}  // namespace data

void cpp_main()
{
    using cppx::Byte;
    using cppx::fail;
    using cppx::size;
    using std::string;
    using std::wstring;

    auto const infobox      = MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_SETFOREGROUND;
    Byte const utf8_bytes[] = // UTF-8 with BOM, as if from a file.
    {
        0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF, 0x42, 0x6C, 0xC3, 0xA5, 0x62, 0xC3, 0xA6,
        0x72, 0x73, 0x79, 0x6C, 0x74, 0x65, 0x74, 0xC3, 0xB8, 0x79,
        0x21, 0x20, 0xE6, 0x97, 0xA5, 0xE6, 0x9C, 0xAC, 0xE5, 0x9B,
        0xBD, 0x20, 0xD0, 0xBA, 0xD0, 0xBE, 0xD1, 0x88, 0xD0, 0xBA,
        0xD0, 0xB0, 0x21, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x48, 0x75, 0x6E,
        0x67, 0x61, 0x72, 0x69, 0x61, 0x6E, 0x20, 0x61, 0x6C, 0x70,
        0x68, 0x61, 0x62, 0x65, 0x74, 0x3A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x41, 0x20,
        0xC3, 0x81, 0x20, 0x42, 0x20, 0x43, 0x20, 0x43, 0x73, 0x20,
        0x44, 0x20, 0x44, 0x7A, 0x20, 0x44, 0x7A, 0x73, 0x20, 0x45,
        0x20, 0xC3, 0x89, 0x20, 0x46, 0x20, 0x47, 0x20, 0x47, 0x79,
        0x20, 0x48, 0x20, 0x49, 0x20, 0xC3, 0x8D, 0x20, 0x4A, 0x20,
        0x4B, 0x20, 0x4C, 0x20, 0x4C, 0x79, 0x20, 0x4D, 0x20, 0x4E,
        0x0D, 0x0A, 0x4E, 0x79, 0x20, 0x4F, 0x20, 0xC3, 0x93, 0x20,
        0xC3, 0x96, 0x20, 0xC5, 0x90, 0x20, 0x50, 0x20, 0x28, 0x51,
        0x29, 0x20, 0x52, 0x20, 0x53, 0x20, 0x53, 0x7A, 0x20, 0x54,
        0x20, 0x54, 0x79, 0x20, 0x55, 0x20, 0xC3, 0x9A, 0x20, 0xC3,
        0x9C, 0x20, 0xC5, 0xB0, 0x20, 0x56, 0x20, 0x28, 0x57, 0x29,
        0x20, 0x28, 0x58, 0x29, 0x20, 0x28, 0x59, 0x29, 0x20, 0x5A,
        0x20, 0x5A, 0x73, 0x0D, 0x0A
    };

    wstring const text = data::utf16_from_utf8( utf8_bytes, size( utf8_bytes ) );
    ::MessageBox( 0, text.c_str(), L"Original text:", infobox );

    string const    sbcs_text           = data::sbcs_from( text, 1250 );

    WORD const      hungarian           = MAKELANGID(
        LANG_HUNGARIAN, SUBLANG_HUNGARIAN_HUNGARY
        );
    DWORD const     hungarian_locale_id = MAKELCID( hungarian, SORT_DEFAULT );

    SetThreadLocale( hungarian_locale_id )
        || fail( "SetThreadLocale", ::GetLastError() );
    DWORD thread_cp = 0;
    ::GetLocaleInfo(
        ::GetThreadLocale(),    // Not LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,
        LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE | LOCALE_RETURN_NUMBER,
        reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>( &thread_cp ),
        sizeof( thread_cp )/sizeof( wchar_t )
        )
        || fail( "GetLocaleInfo", ::GetLastError() );
    //::MessageBox( 0, std::to_wstring( thread_cp ).c_str(), L"Codepage:", MB_SETFOREGROUND );
    assert( thread_cp == 1250 );
    ::MessageBoxA( 0, sbcs_text.c_str(), "SBCS codepage 1250 text:", infobox );
}

auto main()
    -> int
{
    using namespace std;
    try
    {
        cpp_main();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( system_error const& x )
    {
        auto const code = x.code().value();
        cerr << "!" << x.what() << " (code: " << code << ")" << endl;
        return code;
    }
    catch( exception const& x )
    {
        cerr << "!" << x.what() << endl;
        return E_FAIL;
    }
}
```

Example output (Windows messageboxes):

[image]
[image]

And yes, the `dummy` function is an abomination, unsound and ungood, but hey. :)

Comment: This function needs wchar_t and not char array. I have the input in char array and converting char to wchar_t is not so easy. Or I am wrong? I already try this approach, but I also failed.

Comment: you use the wchar_t string for the intermediate UTF-16.

Comment: I found this code http://msmvps.com/blogs/gdicanio/archive/2010/01/04/conversion-between-unicode-utf-16-and-utf-8-in-c-win32.aspx but I'm stuck at CStringW/atlstr.h errors...

Comment: @bartimar: I'll code it up for you but I'm preoccupied with other things, so might not be until tomorrow (possibly this evening).

Comment: Oh thx :) I am sorry, I didnt have time to try it. I will try it on monday, but thx for now :))